# iniciar programa que empiece por unas letras?

Tags: batch

Como puedo hacer esto?

Iniciar programas que tengan determinados caracteres?

Ejemplo

```
start cheaten???.exe
```

o

```
start Chea?e.exe
```

en un batch?

Comment: Es conveniente que compartas que has logrado hasta este momento, con al menos una base de codigo  que demuestre tu investigacion para solucionarlo

Comment: no es investigación leí por hay que es algo para bat con ? o algo asi puedo poner el símbolo en sustitución de una letra pero no entendí bien